# HTML to pdf conversion using wickedpdf with page count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, wicked-pdf

I have html that i need to convert it to pdf using wickedpdf gem and
within html I have div

```
<div class="inner-section" style="page-break-after: always; padding-top: 40px;">
```

With **style page-break-after**
Do we have any functionality of wicked-pdf from which I can calculate that how many pages will that div will take in pdf

why? - I have to create a table of content with page number mentioned in which particular div is present

Comment: I am not certain I understand the question but the readme does show how to generate and/or reference page numbers [Here](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf?tab=readme-ov-file#page-numbering)